# is JSON plugin bundleed wih struts 2.3.4

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, struts2

I am working with Struts 2.3.4 in netbeans.. I need to implement AJAX function in my project.. before starting I had googled around for struts and read somewhere that from struts 2.1+ JSON plugin is bundled with struts distribution. I am following the tutorials on net to implement JSON but I am not able to do so. Can anyone please

1. tell me how do I get the list plugins that have come with the distribution of Struts 2.3.4 in my netbeans IDE
2. give me some links to detailed explanations of Struts Ajax implementation, and adding auto complete feature to dynamically created tables with Struts.

I have implemented all these with core java and javascript using jQuery but I am new to Struts...

NB I am using jQuery javascript framework at the client side

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the JSON plugin is bundled with Struts 2.3.4.

The easiest way to get the list of bundled plugins is to do an `ls` (or `dir` if you're unfortunate enough to be running under Windows):

```
[...b/struts/struts-2.3.4.1/lib]$ ls *plugin*
struts2-codebehind-plugin-2.3.4.1.jar      struts2-osgi-plugin-2.3.4.1.jar
struts2-config-browser-plugin-2.3.4.1.jar  struts2-oval-plugin-2.3.4.1.jar
struts2-convention-plugin-2.3.4.1.jar      struts2-pell-multipart-plugin-2.3.4.1.jar
struts2-dojo-plugin-2.3.4.1.jar            struts2-plexus-plugin-2.3.4.1.jar
struts2-dwr-plugin-2.3.4.1.jar             struts2-portlet-plugin-2.3.4.1.jar
struts2-embeddedjsp-plugin-2.3.4.1.jar     struts2-rest-plugin-2.3.4.1.jar
struts2-gxp-plugin-2.3.4.1.jar             struts2-sitegraph-plugin-2.3.4.1.jar
struts2-jasperreports-plugin-2.3.4.1.jar   struts2-sitemesh-plugin-2.3.4.1.jar
struts2-javatemplates-plugin-2.3.4.1.jar   struts2-spring-plugin-2.3.4.1.jar
struts2-jfreechart-plugin-2.3.4.1.jar      struts2-struts1-plugin-2.3.4.1.jar
struts2-jsf-plugin-2.3.4.1.jar             struts2-testng-plugin-2.3.4.1.jar
struts2-json-plugin-2.3.4.1.jar            struts2-tiles-plugin-2.3.4.1.jar
struts2-junit-plugin-2.3.4.1.jar
```

As to your second question, I'm not sure what "adding autocomplete to a table" would even mean. Tables aren't an input element.

There are literally thousands of jQuery autocomplete examples, and the JSON result should be fairly self-explanatory from the docs. If it isn't, please ask a specific question.

I'd consider using the [Struts 2 jQuery Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/) if possible, as it appears you might be in a little bit over your head; it can make some functionality easier to implement, and there is a strong set of examples.

Comment: thanks @dave..!!
as far as what I meant by adding autocomplete to tables was that I need to dynamically create tables.. In the input text field of the dynamically generated table I need to have auto complete feature.. I am already using struts 2 jQuery plugin in my project...

Comment: @SanketVGarg Then what's the actual question? There are several autocomplete examples, and it's used no differently just because the input element is in a table row.

Comment: if I have got to summerize what I am trying to do then it is as follows..!!
1) create a ajax connection with server and fetch the list of names from server in JSON.
2) create a table dynamically and create table rows like a auto complete jQuery UI widget.. i.e user dose not have type in the entire name as he goes typing auto complete will assist him..
3) I have a button and when user clicks on that button rows are added dynamically to the table I need the same above mentioned features in these dynamically added rows also

Comment: @svg i like how you've written `(or dir if you're unfortunate enough to be running under Windows)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Struts2 with JSON plugin , then u need to down load either of the two jars.

1. jsonplugin0.33.jar or jsonplugin0.34.jar
2. struts-jasonplugin2.1.1.jar

With the first one (either of two from first): you need to as a result type as json in struts.xml with class mentioned as `com.googlecode.json.JSONResult`.

And with the second one, you need to use: `org.apache.json.JSONResult`.